# How can I run my SQL, to get the result such as "John Doe, plumbing"

Tags: sql

I have table **category**, with **id** and **cat_name**

Example: `152, Plumbing`

I have table **user**, with **category_id** and **name**

Example: `152, John Doe`

When I do

`SELECT name, category_id FROM user`

As a result I will have something like

```
John Doe, 152
```

Question:
How can I run my SQL, to get the result such as

```
John Doe, plumbing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try basic **[JOINS](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/joins.php)**

```
SELECT C.cat_name, U.Name
FROM category C JOIN User U ON C.id = U.category_id
```

Comment: Worked, as Expected, thanks. But, how can I display each line each row from sql? Currently my code each line, spamming with all records from SQL

Answer (score 1):

It is quite easy to get this, Please use below query for the same

```
SELECT User.Name, Category.cat_name FROM  User 
INNER JOIN Category ON Category.Id = User.category_id
```

Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
select a.name,b.cat_name from user a, category b 
where a.category_id=b.id
```

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Answer (score 0):

As you can understand you have two tables, and there is some 1 to 1 relationship between records of these tables(user & category).

So here we will use a simple join to connect this two table.

```
SELECT c.cat_name, u.name
FROM category as c, user as u
WHERE c.id = u.category_id
```

When I do `category as c`, this is called aliasing. This has two benefits. One is to keep our query short and sweet(no need to repeat `category`, just use `c`) and second is SQL query engine has 100% clarity of what we want to select.

Let's you also want to select `id`, then you should use `c.id` or `u.category_id`.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Answer (score 0):

Check these alternate methods-

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Category') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE Category
IF OBJECT_ID('User') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [User]

CREATE TABLE Category
(ID INT,Cat_name VARCHAR(20))

CREATE TABLE [User]
(Category_id INT,[Name] VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO Category(ID ,Cat_name)
VALUES (152,'Plumbing')

INSERT INTO [User](Category_id ,[Name])
VALUES (152,'John Doe')

--Method 1 (using CROSS APPLY)
SELECT U.[Name], C.Cat_name FROM [User] U CROSS APPLY Category C WHERE U.Category_id=C.ID
--Method 2 (using INNER JOIN)
SELECT U.[Name], C.Cat_name FROM [User] U INNER JOIN Category C ON U.Category_id=C.ID
--Method 3 (using WHERE and WITHOUT JOIN)
SELECT U.[Name], C.Cat_name FROM [User] U,Category C WHERE U.Category_id=C.ID
```