# SQL Join return zerro, but should return a proper value

Tags: mysql, sql

Thank you very much for previous help - [How can I run my SQL, to get the result such as "John Doe, plumbing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58266989/please-help-me-with-join)

But still I have no luck with JOIN, here is a problem.

I have a tables called - **skills** & **artist**

Table **skills** has *columns*: **id**, **cat_id** and **skill**

Which will be:

```
26 52 Test
27 52 Test2
```

NB: **52** this is **category_id**, which is stored in table - **category**

Table **artist** has *columns*: **name**, **skills**

Which will be:

```
James [26,27]
Putin [26,27]
```

What I have done:

```
select name, skills from artist limit 10
```

It gives me a result, like

```
Putin [26,27]
```

Then I decided to see not ID's but real skills name, so I did

```
select s.skill, a.Name
from skills as s, artist as a
where s.id = a.skills
```

And was expecting, that I will see:

```
Putin [test1, test2]
```

But, instead of this I got

```
MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0008 seconds.)
```

I tried a lot of different ways, can u say, why It is not working, and what I missed?

Comment: You first of all need to fix your data model - storing comma-separated values into a single column is a big NO. You should properly normalize this.

Comment: You mean, returning in SQL something like [25,26] - is bad ?

Comment: _Storing_ multiple values into a single column is “bad”, as you are right now doing with your `skills` column. This should be in an extra table, that connects one artist id with one skill id per row. Please go _read up_ on the keyword database normalization.

Comment: I agree your data model needs to be straightened out.  In any case, what is the data type of `artist.skills` -- is it an `ARRAY`?  What DBMS are you using (i.e. Postgres, MySql)?

Comment: @04FS will read ;)

Comment: @ravioli, artist.skills - mediumtext + InnoDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the tables, group by artist.Name and use group_concat():

```
select a.Name, concat('[', group_concat(s.skill), ']') as skills
from artist as a inner join skills as s
on replace(replace(a.skills, '[', ','), ']', ',') like concat('%,', s.id, ',%')
group by a.Name
```

Comment: Only, one question - you solution, will return only 1 skill per user, [skillName], but what if user have [skillName, skillName] ?

Comment: Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k8xtjugE3ES772ahSgWsvR/0 It returns all the skill names.

Comment: For some reasons, I hve only one skill , even if user has 2 ;) But I thinkg I can fix it.

Comment: Check for spaces between the commas.

Comment: But, now I need to removed spaces in all DB :)

Comment: If you are sure there is only 1 space, use this: `on replace(replace(replace(replace(a.skills, '[', ','), ']', ','), ' ,', ','), ', ', ',') like concat('%,', s.id, ',%')` if you don't want to update the table: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k8xtjugE3ES772ahSgWsvR/1

Comment: Perfect. Awesome. @forpas, is it possible, to remove [  ]  when calling sql in .php? Right now UI return [skills, skill2], can it be done like skill, sill2?

Comment: If you don't want the brackets in the results, instead of: `concat('[', group_concat(s.skill), ']')` use `group_concat(s.skill)`

Comment: but, can I somehow, also display skills one by one? If user has 2 skills - Test1, Test2, can I using sql display only Test1? or Test2?

Comment: OK, for cookies!

Comment: How can I contact you? 
Would like to ask something more about SQL

Comment: Sorry but I don't do any contact outside SO. Anything you want to ask just post a new question.